# Do-while loop not performing correctly

Tags: c++, function, do-while

I have no idea why I am having troubles on this simple thing. I just want the program to ask the user if they want to repeat the process again after all the functions have run when they enter Y or y. When I run the program and enter Y or y, the program loops but it's like it remembers all the values from before so it goes into an infinite error loop.

```
int main()
{
    //declare variables
    const int NUM_NAMES = 20;
    char repeat;
    int nameIndexLoc;
    string searchUser, 
        //array of unsorted elements
        names[NUM_NAMES] = { "Collins, Bill", "Smith, Bart", "Allen, Jim",
                             "Griffin, Jim", "Stamey, Marty", "Rose, Geri",
                             "Taylor, Terri", "Johnson, Jill", "Allison, Jeff",
                             "Looney, Joe", "Wolfe, Bill", "James, Jean",
                             "Weaver, Jim", "Pore, Bob", "Rutherford, Greg",
                             "Javens, Renee", "Harrison, Rose", "Setzer, Cathy",
                             "Pike, Gordon", "Holland, Beth" };
    //do while to continue searching
    do
    {
        //calls function to sort list of names
        selectionSort(names, NUM_NAMES);
        //prints names after they have been sorted
        printSortedNames(names, NUM_NAMES);
        //gets the users name to search for in list
        searchUser = getName();
        //gets index of array where name is found
        nameIndexLoc = getNameIndex(names, NUM_NAMES, searchUser);
        //displays index location of name found
        displaySearchResults(nameIndexLoc);
        //prompt to try again
        cout <<"\n\nWould you like to do another search? (Y/y)" << endl
             << "Or anything else to quit: ";
        cin >> repeat;
    } while (repeat == 'Y'|| repeat == 'y');

    _getch();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You don't change `name` at all. How'd you expect a different result?

Comment: You type in `y` followed by `enter`. The second time around the `enter` is still in the buffer....

Comment: I think cin.clear() will clear the buffer? I am just not sure where to place it.

Comment: @JohnsonNguyen Hopefully it will.

Comment: What does your function `getName` and `getNameIndex`? When your input buffer is empty, users get asked for input of one whole line - which is reused for further reading until it's empty again and another interaction is required. In C++, you `ignore` all characters to clear the buffer and force another prompt.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was in my main right after the user enters in if they wanted to search again.

```
do {

        //calls function to sort list of names
        selectionSort(names, NUM_NAMES);
        //prints names after they have been sorted
        printSortedNames(names, NUM_NAMES);
        //gets the users name to search for in list
        searchUser = getName();
        //gets index of array where name is found
        nameIndexLoc = getNameIndex(names, NUM_NAMES, searchUser);
        //displays index location of name found
        displaySearchResults(nameIndexLoc);
        //prompt to try again
        cout <<"\n\nWould you like to do another search? (Y/y)" << endl
            << "Or anything else to quit: ";
        cin >> repeat;
        cin.ignore();
    } while (repeat == 'Y'|| repeat == 'y');
```

Adding the cin.ignore(); after repeat clears the buffer and allows the program to run correctly.
I can also add it into my other function to get the same results.

```
string getName() {
    //declare variable
    string name;
    //gets user name to search for
    cout << "Enter a name to search for: ";
    cin.clear();
    cin.ignore();
    getline(cin, name);
    return name;
}
```

I will leave it in the getName function because it looks neater.